# Docker without internet

Tags: docker

I am currently working on a project which needs to be deployed on customer infra (which is not cloud) and also it will not have internet.

We currently deploy manually our application and install dependencies using tarball, can docker help us here?

Note:

- Application stack:

  - NodeJs
  - MySql
  - Elasticsearch
  - Redis
  - MongoDB
- We will not have internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) and [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) to load Docker images in TAR format or export these images. If you package your application files within these images this could be used to deliver your project to your customers.

Also note that the destination services must all have Docker Engine installed and running.

Comment: and you have to make sure the destination server has Docker Engine installed and ready to host your containers

Comment: Additionally you should use a docker registry to store your images

Comment: @Thomasleveil, yes you are absolutely correct (although that was implied) but i'll add that for more clarity

Comment: @YonahDissen, that could be a useful solution if there is an internet connection since you can then push the images directly. However when there is no internet connection there is no advantage of this over using the built-in image store in my opinion

Comment: @SvenHakvoort of course if will be useful. Amongst the many reasons to share between different users version control of images and best practices of not relying on local images

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your dev environment, you can also use [Nexus](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images) or [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/) as your private Docker repository. You can then pull your images from there into production, if it makes sense for your product.

I think the most advantage can be had in your local dev setup. Instead of installing, say, MySQL locally, you can run it as a Docker container. I use docker-compose for all client services in my current project. This helps keep your computer clean, makes it easy to avoid versioning hell (if you use different versions for each release or stage) and you don't have to mess around with configuration for each dev machine.

In my previous job every developer had a local Oracle SQL install, and that was not a happy state of affairs.